# Passing data from one component to another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

On component1.vue I have

```
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        editItemNumber: null,
        editBreakdownNumber: null
      }
    }
```

On component2.vue I have a table populated by an array

On that table is an edit button.  Among the item in that table is itemNumber value.  Which I need to assign from that particular row clicked to the editItemNumber on component1.vue

```
<b-table show-empty bordered striped hover :items="itemTableList" :fields="fields">
  <template slot="actions" scope="row">
<b-btn variant='success' size="sm" @click.stop="edit(row.item,row.index,$event.target)">Edit</b-btn>
</template>
</b-table>
```

As you see above originally all of this was on one component and I was just calling to an edit function which repopulated the v-models with that rows contents.  But now with everything split among components I don't know how to edit this to do what I've been tasked with.

I've never used JavaScript, vue or much of anything beyond basic HTML.  I'm a .NET dev who's been tasked with helping out on some web based work and I'm floundering.  So any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't get the question entirely. Can you share more code of your components?

Comment: `component1.vue` is parent for `component2.vue` ? Need more description, or better more code.

Comment: Also, you can quick look to [$emit](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit)-method and this article: [Using with Custom Events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events). 

In a nutshell, the child needs to emit the event, and the parent to subscribe it. When you will emit event, you can pass argument as payload. You will get this payload in subscription place in parent.

Comment: You can prepare minimalistic [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so it will be more understandable, and easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to move data between components is with events.

Normally you use `props` to pass data from a parent component to a child, and events to pass from a child up to a parent.

So the `edit`method of `C2` can be something like

```
edit(item, index, target) {
    const payload = {
        item,
        index,
        target
    };

    this.$emit('edit', payload);
}
```

Then you just have to listen to that event in `C1`. Notice the `@edit` attribute: that means when the `edit` event is fired from `component-one`, run my "edit" method.

```
<template>
<div>
   <p>{{ editItemNumber }}</p>
  <component-two @edit="edit" />
</div>

<script>
export default {
data () {
  return {
    editItemNumber: null,
    editBreakdownNumber: null
  };
},

methods: {
    edit(eventPayload) {
        this.editItemNumber = eventPayload.item.editItemNumber
    }
}
</script>
```

If you both `C1` and `C2` are children of the same parent `P` the idea is the same, except `C1` can't listen directly to `C2`. Instead `P` will listen to the edit event and pass the needed changes down to `C1` through its `props`.

The docs on components are really good, pay special attention to the sections on props and custom events.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Also, if you want some examples of a similar idea, check out this folder on a demo project in my github: https://github.com/akatakritos/vue-scoreboard/tree/master/src/components/GamesAdmin . the GameEntry form fires an event when a game is added, its parent, TheGamesAdminPage, stores it in the API, and then updates its list, which is passed to EditGameList as props.

Comment: I'm reading through that now.  I was able to see how this would function within my components, so thats great.  I've been told I'll need a watcher on component 3 so see when itemNumber is about to change.  I guess I need to also figure out what that's all about next.  Boy I hate being tossed in the deep end let me tell you, but I guess this sometimes is the best learning method.